# FacebookSDK.h' file cannot be found

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, sharekit

I am trying to link the Facebook to my project via Sharekit. I followed the steps on the install wiki but still face issues.

It gives me this error now:

```
'FacebookSDK.h' file cannot be found
```

Comment: friend, better find some other ways, Share-kit methods of facebook integration are outdated.

Comment: like what? tell me i try to integrate...

Comment: It is known problem: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/pull/533 Just wait for a solution

Comment: it should work now, just pull latest commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is said on GitHub official page this should work:

1. Re-installed SK (which may or may not have been actually necessary)
2. cd to ShareKit directory
3. git submodule sync
4. git submodule update

For me worked reverting to previous commit:

```
git checkout -b beforeTargetCleanup 400df71204f48c3367982be2c1dc3158e2e23476
```

Fixed in `52cb63ed784532d0913a264f4a93843b95737392` commit.

Comment: Updated my answer with temporary solution.

Comment: (steps 2-4), i didnt do step #1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I just ran into this today and none of the solutions I found online worked, including following steps 2-4 in @Nekto's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13457103/1191847) from [Sharekit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/pull/533#issuecomment-10515227). I tried a couple of  things and this is what worked for me.

I went into SHKFacebook.m and changed the FacebookSDK.h import from `#import <FacebookSDK.h>` to `"#import <FacebookSDK.h>"` then ran my project on the simulator. After it ran once I was able to change it back to `#import <FacebookSDK.h>` and it still works.